# How to compare QString that convert from QByte?

Tags: qt

Such a weird result, QString that come from Byte, can't be compare to QString.

```
void MainWindow::onFinish(QNetworkReply* response)
{
  QByteArray res = response->readAll();
  QString str("Match");
  
  if(QString(res) == str){
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.setText(QString(res));
    msg.exec();
  }
};
```

Comment: @G.M. Sory, i just typo. i think because response from QNetworkReply. https://pastecode.io/s/5vebr9mt. res can't be compare. but if i  pass directly the res to QMessageBox. It ooutput that res QString.

Comment: @G.M. I updated  my question. The weird here is, if conditional can't check res value. but directly pass to QMessageBox without if conditional. it output the res value.